# How older is this snail shell possible could be?

Tags: geology, paleontology

Last weekend I was in Xınalıq(the village in Azerbaijan) and found this snail shell. I am wondering how old is this?[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not a snail *per se* it's the shell of an [ammonite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ammonoidea) which is more like a squid with an external shell than anything else I can think to compare it to. They went extinct with the dinosaurs so it's at least 65 million years old and could be much older.

Comment: You can tell because snail shells will not by symmetric on one side the coil will be recessed and the other will stick out. in most ammontes both sides of the spiral are concave. because of this the entire spiral is not visible from the concave side of a snail shell.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the Xenodiscaceae (an ammonite family, as the top comment already mentioned.) Based on the region where you found it, my research suggests it is very old, from a time known as the Permian (250 million years to 300 million years ago.)